# Java byte array to Ruby

Tags: java, python, ruby

I have a Desktop application using java swing frames. I have to rewrite the application to either Ruby or python. However I understand java to certain extent - I need help rewriting certain piece of the code in java.

1.

```
byte[] ModuleGuid = new byte[]{
        (byte)0xe1, (byte)0x9a, (byte)0x69, (byte)0x01,
        (byte)0xb8, (byte)0xc2, (byte)0x49, (byte)0x80,
        (byte)0x87, (byte)0x7e, (byte)0x11, (byte)0xd4,
        (byte)0xd8, (byte)0xf1, (byte)0xbe, (byte)0x79
};
```

2.

```
JAVA_PvAPI_SensorInfoEx[] lptSensorInfo =
        new JAVA_PvAPI_SensorInfoEx[(int)PsConstant.JAVA_PvAPI_GET_SENSOR_INFO_MAX];
```

Comment: Asking us to help port code is off-topic. You need to do that work, then, when/as you run into problems, ask about that specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. There's no such thing as `byte` in Ruby. When you want to store a sequence of bytes, you store it in a string:

   ```
   module_guid = "\xE1\x9A\x69\x01...".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')
   ```

   If you want to copy and paste from Java code, then use:

   ```
   module_guid = [0xe1, 0x9a, ...].pack('c*')
   ```

   By the way, I didn't declare the variable as `ModuleGuid` because capitalized identifiers are for constants in Ruby, and I didn't see the `final` keyword in your Java code.
2. Arrays in Ruby are just arrays. They can store any kind of objects. There's no `int[]` or `String[]` or `Whatever[]` in Ruby. Ruby arrays don't have fixed sizes and can be expanded or shrink any time. Your second piece of Java code can be rewritten as:

   ```
   sensor_info = []
   ```

   But, depending on your use-case, this statement itself may not be necessary because in Ruby you have sooooo many ways to obtain an array.

Comment: I'd say `module_guid = "\xE1\x9A\x69\x01...".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')`. On the other hand, `pack('c*')` already does the right thing.

Comment: @Amadan Maybe this is a silly question but what can happen if I don't force encoding?

Comment: For example, `"\xE6\x97\xA5".length` is `1`, because it's one character in UTF-8 (default encoding).

Comment: As I said before, `pack('c*')` already gives you `ASCII-8BIT`-encoded string, so forcing is not necessary there.

Comment: Interesting. `"\xE6\x97\xA5".length` is `1`, but `[0xe6, 0x97, 0xa5].pack('c*').length` is `3`. Ruby really is an intelligent language.